# Using a shell script, How insert a line in a file which starts with a hash?

Tags: shell, unix, hash, ex

I'm trying to insert a line of text beginning with a hash in a text file using a shell script, using something like this:

```
ex run <<EOEX
:i
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH
.
:x
EOEX
```

But I want it to actually insert those lines beginning with the hash, and not treat them as comments. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's what your code does. Is there a problem/question? ([Live demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P7VCoag0T8HGxtXfNYLLKpNLWVE/KTNPPwkoy6Uc7OQY4uzBpcdlVcEFVsCVmpyRr6CkDtSjrpCcn1eSmJlXbKXElZxYAjLn/38A).)

Comment: When I test your script it inserts the comment lines. If it does something else for you, show the contents of `run` before and after running your script.